# How to add a static network with new name system

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I want to add to `/etc/network/interfaces` a new interface to make my IP static and accessible for a SSH connection (to configure a raspberry pi 3b remotely), so I'm using Ubuntu MATE 16.04. For now I'm testing it on a normal Ubuntu 16.04.

Apparently the naming standard for networks has changed and therefore `eth0` is not a valid name anymore.

My raspberry pi is connected to a switch (same network as my computer).

Testing on my laptop (using wlan), `ifconfig` shows 3 networks called enp3s0, lo and wlp2s0, but I can't figure how to set up a static IP, as I learned using eth[0-9] and doesn't seem to work with the new standard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The interfaces now have _stable_ names, meaning that instead of the system enumerating them in an arbirary order and naming them `/dev/eth0`, `/dev/eth1` etc. now they get nice names which are guaranteed to have the same meaning at every boot. In your case `/dev/enp3s0` is the wired Ethernet adapter, `/dev/wlp2s0` is the wireless adapter and `/dev/lo` is the loopback interface (127.0.0.0/8). Use the new names as you would have used `eth0`. How to make a WiFi adapter use a static address is a different problem.

Comment: I'd like to create a static ethernet connection. I'm now on the raspberry Pi and my ethernet looks like this `enxb827ebca21d1` and I don't have any idea why, neither how to name a new one to create it (it won't recognize anything apparently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new persistent naming convention, ethernet interfaces are typically named enp-something. As you see, you have an interface `enp3s0`. Since you say you are connected to a switch, I assume it is with ethernet.

On your normal desktop computer, running recent versions of Ubuntu, you are far better off to set a static IP address in Network Manager, as discussed here: [static ip network guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381112/static-ip-network-guide/381200#381200)

However, if you wish to use `/etc/network/interfaces` in order to learn and to be confident to use the same technique in the Pi, then, first, find out the range of addresses used in the router or other device that serves DHCP on your network. We will select an address outside the DHCP pool. Here is an example: http://www.mathgamehouse.com/oldmgh/istorm/help/manual/images/linksys.gif

In the example, the DHCP pool extends from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.149. If it isn't otherwise reserved, a static address of, in this example, 192.168.1.5 would work perfectly.

Next, I suggest that you amend your file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Of course, substitute your exact details here. Reboot and check:

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are connected.

Comment: Okay this is getting really weird... I did that, rebooted and nothing new showed on `ifconfig`, I can't do `ifup enp3s0`either, it can't find the device. And I also can't ping from other machine to the ip specified in the interface. Surpringily enough, the `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` worked.

Comment: So I gave up and decided to connect the screen and the keyboard and do it manually. It worked. But the struggle continue here http://askubuntu.com/questions/889134/ssh-only-accessible-in-local-network

Comment: Doesn't enp3s0 show in `ifconfig`? Doesn't it have the requested address?