# static-IP problem

Tags: networking

I am pretty new to Ubuntu so i tried to change my static ip and it didn't work. I tried everything still didn't work and no internet. I edited in `/etc/network/interfaces/`

```
auto enp0s3
    iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.0.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway ............
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

i have verify thats enp0s3 its the ethernet
plus i cant find on my router dhcp
what should i do?

- I've also tried Google IPv4 nameservers
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 8.8.4.4

But it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are far better off to set the static IP address in Network Manager as discussed here: [static ip network guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381112/static-ip-network-guide/381200#381200) Second, you can't just ignore the gateway address. I suggest that you check other devices, even iPads or phones, on the network to see what the router address is. That is the gateway address you need to specify. Third, please verify that your ethernet interface is enp0s3; run the terminal command:

```
ifconfig
```

Finally, please be certain that the address you've selected is outside the range used for DHCP in the router.  Here is an example: http://www.mathgamehouse.com/oldmgh/istorm/help/manual/images/linksys.gif

In the example, the DHCP pool extends from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.149. If it isn't otherwise reserved, a static address of, in this example, 192.168.1.5 would work perfectly.

I recommend that you correct your process.

Comment: The gateway is fake didnt want people to know my gateway. my real gateway is there

Comment: Assuming that the real gateway is either 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.254, which is true for half the world, what possible harm could it bring to reveal it? If it isn't 192.168.0.xx, perhaps that is the issue.